# Hooking a function

Tags: c++

Im using VS2019 and I want to hook function in module that is loaded into process
this is function code

```
void C::GetDrawPosition(float* pX, float* pY, bool* pbBehindCamera, QAngle angleCrosshairOffset)
{
    ...

    * pX = x;
    * pY = y;
    *pbBehindCamera = bBehindCamera;
}
```

...

```
class C
{
public:
       static void  GetDrawPosition ( float *pX, float *pY, bool *pbBehindCamera, QAngle angleCrosshairOffset = vec3_angle );
};
```

and this is function prototype and how I am hooking it

```
typedef void(__cdecl *GetDrawPosition_t) (float*, float*, bool*, QAngle);
extern GetDrawPosition_t GetDrawPosition_s;
```

...

```
GetDrawPosition_t GetDrawPosition_s = nullptr;

DWORD GetDrawPosition_adr = GetClientSig("55 8B EC ...");
XASSERT(GetDrawPosition_adr);

GetDrawPosition_s = (GetDrawPosition_t)DetourFunction((LPBYTE)GetDrawPosition_adr,(LPBYTE)&Hooked_GetDrawPosition);
```

and my Hook

```
void __cdecl Hooked_GetDrawPosition(float* pX, float* pY, bool* pbBehindCamera, QAngle angleCrosshairOffset)
{
    *pX = *pX - 400;
    *pY = *pY - 101;
    
    GetDrawPosition_s(pX, pY, pbBehindCamera, angleCrosshairOffset);
}
```

the problem is that it doesnt make any changes, I tried to use different convension types, I dont know what I did wrong, signature is correct 100%

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: In new Detours it's `DetourAttach` and `DetoursDetach`. Detours 1.0 was designed for VS2005, not sure how that would work with 2019...  btw. Is `C` a class?

Comment: yeah C is class, tried to minimize the code for @Alan Birtles,
btw I use Detours Version 1.5 (Build 46), worked for me in VS2019 in any other program, I dont see the problem, maybe convension type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `C` is a class and `GetDrawPosition` is not a static member function, then type of `C::GetDrawPosition(float* pX, float* pY, bool* pbBehindCamera, QAngle angleCrosshairOffset)` isn't `void(__cdecl *GetDrawPosition_t) (float*, float*, bool*, QAngle)`, its type is

```
 void(__cdecl C::*GetDrawPosition_t) (float*, float*, bool*, QAngle)
```

Which expects that you have to pass a pointer to object instance of type `C` somehow.

You can't detour non-static methods directly, not at least in Detour 1.0. I saw examples (which you can find online)  for 2.0\ 3.0 Express

Comment: sorry I forget to add declaration of that function
`static void GetDrawPosition ( float *pX, float *pY, bool *pbBehindCamera, QAngle angleCrosshairOffset = vec3_angle );` inside C class

Comment: @MatejP then something wrong with  `GetClientSig`, whatever that is

Comment: My bad, everything was working correctly, idk why I started to find problem